# В ответ на запрос по дефолту приходит index.html, хотя я отправляю свою строку

Tags: java, glassfish

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/API"})
public class API extends HttpServlet {
private String requestName;

@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String simpleResponse = "resp";
    BufferedOutputStream bs = null;

    try {
        response.setContentType("text/xml");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        bs = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
        bs.write(simpleResponse.getBytes());

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        bs.flush();
        bs.close();
    }
}
```

В ответ приходит index.html

Как исправить?